# Behaviour of char and short datatype when reading through %d format specifier

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation, scanf, union

I'm trying to perform **"BIT MANIPULATION"** operation using struct and union(without any bitwise operators).
While doing so I Encountered with some minor bug, i.e., if i use "char" and "short" datatype I'm unable to get desired output, instead if I use "int" datatype I got desired output.
So I didn't understood what is happening in scanf() when reading char or short datatype variable with %d.
here 'num1' variable will store user entered number,'pos' variable which stores bit position & 'val' is variable which is storing value '0' or '1' which is need to be replaced.

By using char/short datatype it is reading correct position value which is entered by user, but inside 'switch' statement it is going to "default" condition.
But when I use 'int' datatype, inside switch statement it is going to correct case label.

code:

```
 int main()
{
    union bit_operations
    {
        unsigned char num;
        struct bit_field
        {
        unsigned char b1:1;
        unsigned char b2:1;
        unsigned char b3:1;
        unsigned char b4:1;
        unsigned char b5:1;
        unsigned char b6:1;
        unsigned char b7:1;
        unsigned char b8:1;
        }p;

}u;
    
    
    unsigned char num1;
    char pos,val;
    printf("enter the num\n");
    scanf("%x",&num1);
    u.num=num1;
    printf("value entered is %x\n",u.num);
    
    while(1){
    printf("enter bit position(in range 1-8)\n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    
    printf("pos value is %d\n",pos);
    
    printf("For SET->1\nFor REST->0\n");
    scanf("%d",&val);
        
switch(pos)
{
    case 1: u.p.b1=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;

    case 2: u.p.b2=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;
    
    case 3: u.p.b3=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;

    case 4: u.p.b4=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;
    
    case 5: u.p.b5=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;

    case 6: u.p.b6=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;

    case 7: u.p.b7=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;

    case 8: u.p.b8=val;
            printf("0X%X\n",u.num);
    break;

    default:printf("entered wrong bit position");
            
}
    
    
}
return 0;
}
```

here is output:-

```
enter the num
ff
value entered is ff
enter bit position(in range 1-8)
4
pos value is 4
SET->1
REST->0
0
entered wrong bit position
enter 10 to EXIT
 or
enter bit position(in range 1-8)
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Right there `unsigned char num1; scanf("%x",&num1);` is just invalid. Don't you get a warning message from your compiler?

Comment: You can't use %x and %d for `char` but only for `int`. Change `char pos,val;` to `int pos,val;`. Using `scanf` with types non matching format specifiers results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KamilCuk 
actually i didn't got any kind of warning while compiling. I choose **unsigned char** bcz i'm performing operation on 1byte data ,so if I take**int** then i will allocate 4Bytes of memory and remaining 3bytes go unused.

Answer (score 0):

As defined here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is **undefined**.

And the conversion specifier `%d` or `%x`, is for

> signed int* or unsigned int*

i.e. not for `char*`, i.e. not valid for it.

So the "Behaviour of char and short datatype when reading through %d format specifier" is undefined.

Comment: but I what is learnt is **char** is also an int datatype with 1Byte size and which stores value -127to 128 or 0-255.
If we use %c it reads /prints character for that corresponding decimal value and if we use %d it prints decimal value.

Comment: It is an integer datatype, or can be used as such, but it simply is not one of the types which the specifiers are meant for.

Answer (score 0):

To `scanf` `unsigned char` you need to use proper *length modifier* inside *format specifier*:

```
unsigned char num1;
char pos,val;
int r = scanf("%hhx", &num1);
if (r) abort(); // scanf _may_ fail. Do not forget to handle errors.
r = scanf("%hhd", &pos);
if (r) abort(); // scanf _may_ fail. Do not forget to handle errors.
r = scanf("%hhd", &val);
if (r) abort(); // scanf _may_ fail. Do not forget to handle errors.
```

The `hh` length modifier makes `scanf` scan for `unsigned char` or `signed char` depending on specifier.

Note that you do not need `hh` for `printf`. That is a quirk of C, because each argument inside [variadic argument list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) undergoes [implicit integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions).

The *best* ways is not care at all and care about compiler warnings. Always try to enable all warnings in your compile. [Your code when compiled with gcc -Wall -Wextra on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4MW63) produces:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:26:13: warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int *', but argument 2 has type 'unsigned char *' [-Wformat=]
   26 |     scanf("%x",&num1);
      |            ~^  ~~~~~
      |             |  |
      |             |  unsigned char *
      |             unsigned int *
      |            %hhx
<source>:32:13: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
   32 |     scanf("%d",&pos);
      |            ~^  ~~~~
      |             |  |
      |             |  char *
      |             int *
      |            %hhd
<source>:37:13: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
   37 |     scanf("%d",&val);
      |            ~^  ~~~~
      |             |  |
      |             |  char *
      |             int *
      |            %hhd
Compiler returned: 0
```

---

I see little point in writing an union and then passing it to big fat `switch`. The code essentially just does:

```
if (1 <= pos && pos <= 7) {
   u.num = 1 << (pos - 1);
   // or maybe you want MSB order, like:
   // u.num = 1 << (8 - pos);
   printf("0X%X\n", u.num);
} else {
    // wrong pos;
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for ur response and clarification. Till now I'm unware of **%hhx , %hhd**  I appreciate for your contribution and making me to learn new stuff.
Can briefly say about %hh format specifier, what is difference b/w %x and %hhx and why we need to go for it

Comment: The difference is that `%x` takes `unsigned int` argument and `%hhx` takes `unsigned char` argument. `printf` and `scanf` (and any variadic function for that matter) have to know what arguments you pass to them, so they know what to get from stack. If you pass wrong format specifier for the type of argument, data on stack will be interpreted differently then they are.